# R - contour plot for hexagonal grid?

Tags: r, plot, contour

Suppose I have a grid of n hexagons (the output of a Self Organized Map), where hexagons are represented by the values of their centers and the diameter. Each hexagon is associated to a z-value that I wish to plot. This way, each hexagon gets its color based on its z-value.

How can I "blur" the borders between the hexagons? That is, is there a way to make a contour plot of the z-values such that the hexagonal structure is preserved?

Comment: it's not the same as countour plot with hexagons centers a 2D point coordinates and Z as "z"?

Comment: not really, because there's also the diameter, I think it fits in the equation somehow?

Comment: so, in your case, the diameter would fit as a "margin" around the center, so I guess one possible approach could be to adding extra points at + - radius distances around the centers. Then you would get these extra coutour lines which in turn with different colours would represent "bands" or "strips" of similar values and still preserve your topology.

Comment: Yes, that was my basic intuition. Do you by any chance know of methods that could achieve this? It's a sort of matrix expansion by interpolation, I tried googling it but nothing interesting showed. Maybe I am just posing the wrong question.

Comment: And why not a contour plot? Do you know how to plot them?  https://plot.ly/r/contour-plots/